# CRM transferring phonecall activity to a new Entity shows it on both Entities

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to move the activities on some of our contacts/accounts to a `new_private_contact_details` entity. I have all of them but the phonecall working. The below code does seem to work, but it ends up showing the phonecall on the activity feed for both the `new_private_contact_details` entity as well as the existing `Contact` entity. Obviously this is a problem, since I'm trying to migrate those kinds of details to the private details, so having them still show up voids that process.

```
if (phoneCallsList != null && phoneCallsList.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (PhoneCall pc in phoneCallsList)
    {
        if (pc.StatusCode.Value != 1)
        {
            int oldState = 0; //for the beginning statecode
            int oldStatus = 0; //for the beginning statuscode

            if (pc.StatusCode.Value == 3)
            {
                oldState = 2;
                oldStatus = 3;
            }
            else
            {
                oldState = 1;
                oldStatus = pc.StatusCode.Value;
            }

            //change status to open
            SetStateRequest setStateRequest = new SetStateRequest()
            {
                EntityMoniker = new EntityReference
                {
                    Id = pc.Id,
                    LogicalName = pc.LogicalName
                },
                State = new OptionSetValue(0),
                Status = new OptionSetValue(1)
            };
            try
            {
                crm.Execute(setStateRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex);
            }
            pc.RegardingObjectId = pcd.ToEntityReference();
            pc.StatusCode.Value = 1;
            try
            {
                service.Update(pc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex);
            }
            //return status to closed
            setStateRequest = new SetStateRequest()
            {
                EntityMoniker = new EntityReference
                {
                    Id = pc.Id,
                    LogicalName = pc.LogicalName
                },
                State = new OptionSetValue(oldState),
                Status = new OptionSetValue(oldStatus)
            };
            try
            {
                crm.Execute(setStateRequest);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pc.RegardingObjectId = pcd.ToEntityReference();
            try
            {
                service.Update(pc);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have already handled for when the phonecall is completed/closed. I'm updating the `RegardingObjectId`, but it doesn't remove it from the original entity, and deleting it in CRM from either entity, deletes it from both.

Again, I only seem to be having this issue with the `phonecall` entity. This code works perfectly for the others, i.e., `appointments`, `tasks`, `letters`, and `emails`

Comment: Why all of the Try Catches, that remove the custom Error types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out where the problem was occurring. It showed up on both entities, because for `PhoneCalls` there is also a `PhoneCalls.To` field that still referenced the old `Contact` entity. Unfortunately this field requires a `PartyList`, which, from what I've found, cannot be customized, so it must always point to a `Contact`, `Lead`, `Opportunity` or `Account` entity.